# Better / proper translation of "包容" in English

Tags: word-request, phrase-request

I looked at the translation of "包容" in English, and both google translate and the [collinsdictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/chinese-english/%E5%8C%85%E5%AE%B9) say it means "tolerate".

However, that's not the meaning/message/idea I want to convey, as my understanding is that the meaning of "tolerate" is more close to "bear" (忍受), whereas I want to find a word/phrase of tolerating ***small inconvenient*** things and to use in the sentence to thank them.

For example, say we've agreed on something already and I just want to make a little new change, which the other party would surely agree, yet I want to apologize such ***small inconvenience*** and thank them for tolerating that.

The word came to my mind was "incorporate" --

> Thank you to have *incorporated* our latest change ...

But I looked it up and found "incorporate" doesn't have such meaning. So maybe *"live with"*, or anything better?

Another example,

> Sorry that I have to call and bother you many times, thank you for ___ing my interruptions.

Comment: I think the expression you might be looking for is  **Sorry for any inconvenience**.  We don't use "thanks" in this context, but rather offer an apology instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe this is what you're looking for:

> Thank you for *accommodating* our last-minute changes.

But that wouldn't work for your other example.  You can say:

> Sorry that I have to call and bother you many times, thank you for *enduring* / *bearing with* / *putting up with* my interruptions.

Comment: Thanks for the to-the-point answer, and yes, _accommodate_ & _put up with_ fit my example situation quite well.

Answer (score 3):

I suspect there is a cultural difference.  As I understand your situation, you are making some minor textual changes, not substantial but more like "fixing a spelling mistake" or "correcting a minor grammatical error".

I don't think I would thank the other person for anything in this situation, indeed I might expect to be thanked! Your example seems a little "grovelling".

> I've attached the final version of the contract.  There are No major changes. I've fixed the spelling of "practise" on page 3.

If the changes are necessary or useful, then they aren't an inconvenience.  If they aren't necessary or useful, then don't make them!  Only apologise if you think you've done something wrong.  And then don't thank someone - you shouldn't thank someone for accepting your apology as that is presumptious.

> I'm sorry but I'm going to have to make one final change.  My manager would like the termination date to be brought forward by two days to avoid clashing with a national holiday here.  I hope that's not a problem.  My final version of the contract is attached.

So here there is an apology, but no "thanks".

Finally, if the person has accepted your apology, you *might* thank then.

> Thank you for being so understanding.

> Thank you for agreeing to this last-minute change.

> Thank you for being flexible.

Comment: Yes, _"being understanding"_ and _acceptable_ is the key meaning of the Chinese word "包容". Upvoting!